# Error in proving Lagrange's Identity for $1+\cos\theta+\cdots+\cos n\theta$

Tags: complex-analysis, trigonometry, proof-verification

Note: I was originally trying essentially to prove the same thing as this [Finalising proof of Lagrange's Trig Identity](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2418444/finalising-proof-of-lagranges-trig-identity). However, I do not consider my question to be a duplicate. **I am looking for someone to point out my mistake in my "proof," not to prove it for 
me.**

---

**My attempted "proof"**

> My goal was to show 
>   $$1+\cos\theta+\cdots+\cos n\theta= \frac12+\frac{\sin\frac{(2n+1)\theta}{2}} {2\sin\frac{\theta}{2}}$$ when $0<\theta<2 \pi$.

I see that 
$$\begin{align}LHS
&= \Re\left(\frac {1-e^{i(n+1)\theta}} {1-e^{i\theta}}\right) \tag{1}\\[4pt]
&= \frac {(\cos\theta-1)(\cos((n+1)\theta)-1)+\sin((n+1)\theta)\sin\theta} {(\cos\theta-1)^2+\sin^2\theta} \tag{2}\\[4pt]
&=\frac{(\cos\theta-1)(\cos n\theta \cos \theta-\sin n\theta \sin\theta-1)+(\sin n\theta \cos\theta + \cos n\theta \sin\theta)\sin\theta} {2-2\cos\theta} \tag{3} \\[4pt]
&= \frac {\cos n\theta-\cos\theta-\cos n\theta \cos\theta +\sin n\theta \sin\theta +1} {2-2\cos\theta} \tag{4}\\[4pt]
&=\frac12+\frac12\cos n\theta+ \frac{\sin n\theta \sin\theta} {2-2\cos\theta} \tag{5}
\end{align}$$

To finish proof, it suffices to show that 
$$\frac {\sin\frac{(2n+1)\theta}{2}} {2\sin\frac{\theta}{2}}=\frac12\cos n\theta+\frac{\sin n\theta \sin\theta} {2-2\cos\theta} \tag{6}$$

By our restriction on $\theta$, we must have $\sin\frac\theta2=\sqrt{\frac12(1-\cos \theta)}$.

We see that $\cos^2\frac\theta{2}=\frac12(1+\cos \theta)$.

**Case 1:** Suppose $\cos\frac{\theta}{2}=\sqrt{\frac12(1+cos \theta)}$. Then

$$\begin{align}
\frac {\sin\frac{(2n+1)\theta}{2}} {2\sin\frac{\theta}{2}} 
&= \frac{\sin n\theta \cos\frac{\theta}{2}+\cos n\theta \sin\frac{\theta}{2}} {2\sin\frac{\theta}{2}} \tag{7} \\[4pt]
&=\frac{\cos n\theta}{2}+\frac {\sin n \theta \sqrt {1+\cos \theta}} {2 \sqrt {1-\cos \theta}} \tag{8} \\[4pt]
&=\frac12\cos n\theta + \frac{\sin n \theta \sin \theta} {2-2\cos \theta} \tag{9}
\end{align}$$
as needed.

**Case 2:** Suppose $\cos\frac{\theta}{2}=-\sqrt{\frac12(1+\cos\theta)}$. Then, by similar logic, I obtained 
$$\frac{\sin\frac{(2n+1)\theta}{2}} {2\sin\frac{\theta}{2}}= \frac12 \cos n \theta- \frac{\sin n \theta \sin \theta} {2-2\cos \theta} \tag{10}$$
but this seems wrong to me.

> Where's my mistake?

Comment: How about [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2618462/proving-complex-series-1-cos-theta-cos2-theta-cos-n-theta/2618474#2618474)? It's shorter and starts the same way.

Comment: @rtybase +1 That was really helpful and solved my problem, even if it doesn't *technically* answer my "question."